# Changing page zoom of an existing pdf with PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have a pdf which I'm iterating through using `PDFBox` as below:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytearray));
PDDocumentCatalog catalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
for(PDPage page : catalog.getPages()){
    ...     
}
```

I want to set the default magnification for the pages so that when it is opened through a pdf reader, it opens at `75%` zoom by default. Is this possible? I've seen few posts where the zoom is set using `PDPageXYZDestination`, but I'm not sure whether that is applicable in my case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this, it applies to the first seen page only, i.e. when opening:

```
PDDocumentCatalog catalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog();
PDPage page = doc.getPage(0); // zero-based; you can also put another number to jump to a specific existing page
PDPageXYZDestination dest = new PDPageXYZDestination();
dest.setPage(page);
dest.setZoom(0.75f);
dest.setLeft((int) page.getCropBox().getLowerLeftX());
dest.setTop((int) page.getCropBox().getUpperRightY());
PDActionGoTo action = new PDActionGoTo();
action.setDestination(dest);
catalog.setActions(null);
catalog.setOpenAction(action);
doc.save(...);
```

Comment: Thx. But can I set the zoom for all the pages? This method seems to be setting the `PDActionGoTo` to the catalog, which means I can just set the zoom for any one page?

Also, isn't there a simpler way to do this? It looks like a lot of work just for changing the zoom.

Comment: I don't know of any such setting. The zoom thing is for destinations, this is for opening, for actions, and for bookmarks. I don't know of an easier way; PDFBox is very low level.

Comment: Thanks, your method works if I download and open the pdf in a reader. Is there a way I could achieve the same thing if the pdf is opened in a browser? I know that there are `PDFOpenParameters` that I could use for zoom. But the problem is, I  have an API which returns the pdf as a `ResponseEntity<byte[]>`. So the API end point would look something like `abc.com/getpdf`. But it looks like the open parameters work only for direct pdf files (i.e) if I open the pdf file in the browser.

Comment: There is an issue here: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/5009 but then nothing happened.